# retrieve distinct sentence that contains words in order

Tags: mysql, search

using MySQL, if you have a table of sentences, and a table of words with a many-to-many table that contains their relationships, how would you structure a query to find a sentence that contains a phrase?

For example, using these tables...

```
Words
1 apples
2 like
3 I
4 used
5 to
6 eat

Sentences
1 I used to like apples
2 I used to eat apples

Words2Sentences
pkey fk_word fk_sentence
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 3 1
4 4 1
5 5 1
6 1 2
7 3 2
8 4 2
9 5 2
10 6 2
```

How would you structure a join and query in order to find the phrase "used to". Full text index is not going to suit my needs, due to multilanguage support requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN` and `LIKE` in `WHERE` clause. See below:

```
SELECT 
      Words,Sentences
FROM Words A 
INNER JOIN Words2Sentences B A.fk_word=B.fk_word
INNER JOIN Sentences C B.fk_sentence=C.fk_sentence
WHERE Sentences LIKE '%used to%'
```

Comment: i dont understand how this is different from SELECT sentence FROM sentences WHERE sentence LIKE '%used to%'. the end result record we're going for is the sentence row. This query would return a record like "The man refUSED TO eat apples"

Answer (score 0):

Use **INNER JOIN ** with **LIKE** in **WHERE** Clause

```
SELECT ws.pkey,w.words,s.sentences FROM Words2Sentences as ws
INNER JOIN Words as w ON w.fk_word = ws.fk_word
INNER JOIN Sentences as s ON s.fk_sentence = ws.fk_sentence
WHERE s.sentences RLIKE '%[[:>:]] used to [[:<:]]%' GROUP BY ws.pkey ORDER BY ws.pkey
```

Comment: i dont understand how this is different from SELECT sentence FROM sentences WHERE sentence LIKE '%used to%'. the end result record we're going for is the sentence row. This query would return a record like "The man refUSED TO eat apples".